# Must click twice to active onclick event JavaScript

Tags: javascript, onclick, dom-events

I need to click twice on the div (`class="funfact"`) in order to active `onclick` event `ff0()`.
Yes, I included the JS script in the HTML file.

```js
var ffans = document.querySelector(".funfactans");

//ffans = fun fact answer
function ff0() {
  if (ffans[0].style.height == '0px') {
    ffans[0].style.height = '45px'
    ffans[0].style.marginBottom = '10px'
    ffans[0].style.paddingRight = '10px'
    ffans[0].style.visibility = 'visible'
    ffans[0].style.opacity = '1'
    ffans[0].style.pointerEvents = 'auto'
  }
```

```html
<div class="facts">
  <div class="funfact" onclick="ff0()">Fact1</div>
  <div class="funfactans">Fact1 answer</div>
</div>
<script src="mainNew.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your JS is not complete. Please update the snippet I made you

Comment: Also please just do a `document.querySelector(".funfactans").classList.add("otherclass")` and put all the styles in your stylesheet

Comment: Lastly height="0px" vs visibility and another height is the difference between display:none and display:block

Comment: Is not ```document.querySelector(".funfactans")``` enough?

Comment: Can you please write me an answer as an answer and not as a comment? It's hard for me to understand that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- height="0px" vs visibility and another height is the difference between display:none and display:block
- .style.height == '0px' cannot be tested like that

I believe you want this

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.querySelector(".facts").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt.classList.contains("funfact")) {
      tgt.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("hide");
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.funfactans {
  height: 45px;
  marginBottom: 10px;
  paddingRight: 10px;
  pointerEvents: auto;
}

.hide {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<title>FunFacts</title>

<div class="facts">
  <div class="funfact">Fact1</div>
  <div class="funfactans hide">Fact1 answer</div>
  <div class="funfact">Fact2</div>
  <div class="funfactans hide">Fact2 answer</div>
</div>
```